# Need tips on how to achieve a thread-safe queue in fs2 (Scala)

Tags: scala, fs2

I need to implement a microservice that loads a ton of data into memory at startup and makes that data available via HTTP GET. 
I have been looking at fs2 as an option to make the data available to the web layer via an `fs2.Queue`.

My concern is that if I use the `synchronous` queue from `fs2`, my performance of serving the data might be affected negatively because of the blocking nature of the `synchronous` queue (on `enqueue` operation).

Is this a valid concern? 
Also, which `Queue` abstractions (in fs2) are thread-safe? ie: can I pass any Queue around to multiple threads and can they all safely take items out of the queue without more than one of them taking the same element out of the queue?

EDIT: 
Use case: 10Mil records served by the Stream -> many workers (threads) picking work from the Stream via a HTTP endpoint (GET)

Comment: So without your data being served into the queue, actually the microservice is not up and running right?

Comment: What do you mean by "make data available"? Do you serve data based on a specific key? FIFO? can you elaborate a bit more on the use case?

Comment: Edited with use case. Please let me know if it requires more clarification

Comment: @Armin your question is far too broad. the semantics of `fs2.concurrent.Queue.synchronous` are such that at most _one_ element can be enqueued. all fs2 queues are thread-safe, that's why they live in a package called `fs2.concurrent`. you question boils down to "which queue should i use?". the answer will depend entirely on your use case/traffic/load. experiment with different queues, measure the results, choose the one that works best.